# Connecting external mySql to Google App Engine

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, google-app-engine

I have hosted a database at www.freemysqlhosting.net/. Also, I have a Google APP Engine project , through which I would like to connect to the said database. I read that external requests are not possible in GAE, and one has to use urlFetch. But, without any other server to process some kind of web api, is it possible to do this ?

www.freemysqlhosting.net/, as far as i know, only hosts the website.

Comment: Is your app written in Python, java, php or Go?

Comment: sorry for not mentioning. its PHP

Comment: @harvey_slash were you able to connect to external mysql? if so can you post sample code for the connection? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the database can be accessed using an ip address/port combination then all you need to do is enable billing on your application so you can access the sockets apis - and you should be good to go.

[Sockets API reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/sockets/)

Comment: im using the free quota of my GAE . will this work ?

Comment: also , can you please tell me what the syntax to connect to an external database using sockets api is?

Comment: it would be helpful if you gave some example, or syntax.

Comment: sockets only work on apps with billing enabled. you just use the normal mysql api to connect to your database: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: Is it free? Is there any method that is completely free?

Comment: there's a free quota - how much it would cost depends on how much you use.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, it works but I am having some issues connecting still

Comment: Thanks Stuart, it works but I am still having some Connecting Issues, 
backend error (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1045, \"Access denied for user 'users_db'@'107.278.239.162' (using password: YES)\")" 

This happens because 107.278.239.162 is changing and I have to add this IP as Allowed Host.

Any way to set Hostname instead of variable IPs for request made by App Engine to external servers. I already have Custom Domains configured

Comment: You have to get a staticc ip address, ie: IP address that does not change.